# I need to match smallest occurence with regular expressions

Tags: regex

i have some trouble with this reg exp case :

Text:
COSAAATANZOSALVAOOOTORRRE

Reg Exp
C[A-Z]*S[A-Z]+T?

this give me this match

COSAAATANZOSALVAOOOT

but i need this match:

COSAAAT

how i can do it?

Comment: I think `(#)` should not be part of the regex, but you can make the quantifiers non greedy `C[A-Z]*?S[A-Z]+?T` https://regex101.com/r/JxApPK/1

Answer (score 0):

You can make you quantifiers lazy by adding a ?. Like so:

```
C[A-Z]*?S[A-Z]+?T
```

Comment: C[A-Z]*?S[A-Z]*?T this work better also for other case, but thank you!